go: unknown revision of workspace module
I have a common-libs repo which consists of some shared code. It is structured using go workspaces and the file structure looks like this:
.
├── go.work
├── go.work.sum
├── middleware
│   ├── <some code>
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum


As you can see it has one go module under directory middleware.
I updated that repo and created a new release in Github and tagged it v1.0.1.
I have a second repo api which imports the common-libs/middleware module like:
import "github.com/MyOrg/common-libs/middleware

I wanted to update the dependency version so in api I changed go.mod file to
require (
    github.com/MyOrg/common-libs/middleware v1.0.1
)


Now when I run go get ./... it fails with a following error:
go: github.com/MyOrg/common-libs/middleware@v1.0.1: reading github.com/MyOrg/common-libs/middleware/go.mod at revision middleware/v1.0.1: unknown revision middleware/v1.0.1

I don't understand why it tries to find a tag with a prefix middleware. What's the right way to version submodule from a go workspace? Should I create a release with prefix middleware/v1.0.1 for it to work?

If middleware is a separate module within common-libs, then yes you should prefix the tag with the correct path.
